# Remove column name from the result of ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I got the response with column name **key**, but I don't need it. How to get the response without the column name.

That is I don't need the key : time, high, low, ...

I just need the result values.

I got the result by  `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(q_cmd)`

```
{"time"=>"2014-01-02 01:14:00", "high"=>"2360", "low"=>"2360", "open"=>"2360", "close"=>"2360", "volume"=>"9"}{"time"=>"2014-01-02 01:14:01", "high"=>"0", "low"=>"0", "open"=>"0", "close"=>"0", "volume"=>"0"}{"time"=>"2014-01-02 01:14:02", "high"=>"0", "low"=>"0", "open"=>"0", "close"=>"0", "volume"=>"0"}{"time"=>"2014-01-02 01:14:03", "high"=>"0", "low"=>"0", "open"=>"0", "close"=>"0", "volume"=>"0"}{"time"=>"2014-01-02 01:14:04", "high"=>"0", "low"=>"0", "open"=>"0", "close"=>"0", "volume"=>"0"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result being a `Hash`, you can call `values` on it:

```
res = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(q_cmd)
res.values
```

This will give you just the values in an array!

Reference documentation: [`Hash#values`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-values).